# Android Retrofit throwing exception instead of showing response

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, androidhttpclient

My following code throws an exception instead of showing the response:

```
fun getRoadStatus(roadName: String) {
        // Couroutine to fetch data from the API
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try{
                _busy.value = true
                println("Getting result")
                _dataObject.value = MyApi.retrofitService.getRoadStatus(roadName)[0]
                _busy.value = false
            } catch (e:Exception) {
                println(e)
                _busy.value = false
            }
        }
    }
```

my _dataObject.value should be loaded with data sent from the server with a message and status code of 404 but instead my code enters into an Exception with a 404. How can access my object data for this error from the server please?

Comment: share the API response?

Comment: please share your Exception message, your model too